# Ruby: What is `->>`?

Tags: ruby

I across this operator `->>` in some Ruby code.

```
 scope :boosted_via_additional_articles, lambda {
    where("boost_states ->> 'boosted_additional_articles' = 'true'")
  }
```

That is this operator?

Comment: Update your tags. Are you using Postgres? If so that's a json/jsonb operator ([see](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html)).

Comment: I'm just reading source code. I'm not using anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `->>` is inside a string, so it is not actually part of Ruby syntax.  It is part of whatever library you are using which defines the `scope` method.  You should refer to the documentation of that library (maybe ActiveRecord).

Answer (score 3):

Like @DavidGrayson said, it’s a string whose meaning is defined by whatever receives that string instead of Ruby. It seems likely that in this case, it’s eventually received by PostgreSQL, and is [getting a JSON field as text](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html).